# Change variable after page load on an iframe using Tampermonkey

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-chrome, iframe, tampermonkey

So far I am able to change any varialbe on the top level of the webpage via

```
window.xhttp = variable = true;
```

The problem is that the variable I need to change is located within an iframe, so when I execute

```
window.xhttp = API.Example.Var = true;
```

An error is returned because it does not recognize the external script since it was only loaded in the iframe, not the actual webpage.

Although in chrome if I change the focus of the console to the iframe I'm easily able to change the variable using the console. This may just be a dumb question and  I might be missing something very simple. But would love some help, thanks!

Comment: make the tampermonkey hit the iframe url, not the top page url.

Comment: @match applies to x.com/x/page/* the top page url is x.com/x/page, the iframe url is x.com/x/page/x, technically wouldnt that be covered under *